# Written function not running

Tags: r, function

I'm getting an "Error in beta * sig2[i - 1] : non-numeric argument to binary operator" message when I try to run this (written) function on a chunk of test code.  Can anyone explain the error or how to fix it?

```
my.garch11.filter <- function(Y, GARCH){
  T <- length(Y)
  
  omega <- GARCH[1]
  alpha <- GARCH[2]
  bets <- GARCH[3]
  GARCH <- c(omega, alpha, beta)
  
  for(i in 2:T){
    sig2 <- rep(0, length = T)
    sig2[1] <- var(Y)
    sig2[i] <- (omega + (alpha * T[i-1]^2) + (beta * sig2[i-1]))
    
    z[i] <- T[i] / sqrt(sig2[i])
    
    loglik <- ((-(T/2) * log(2*pi)) - ((1/2) * (log(sig2[i:T]))) - ((1/2)*(Y[i]^2)/sig2[i]))
  }
  
  return(sig2, z)
}
```

Comment: 5th line, bets? Maybe it is beta?

Comment: also, the use of T (base assigned to TRUE) as a variable can lead to several problems, maybe will be better the use of t instead of T

Comment: and also, z variable not declared, add z=NULL and trying to return a multi-argument, try return(list(sig2 = sig2, z = z))